Thread 1.3 on ESP32-C6: How to asynchronously respond to messages
I am trying to connect two beetle esp32-c6 together in a Thread 1.3 network. They are both flashed with the same code. If they detect there is a network they join it. If there is no network then they create a network and become its leader. If they are the leader they send out a broadcast message ("Hello I am your leader."). If they are a node they send a message only to the leader ("Hello from a node.").
The code has this compilation error Compilation error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermissive]. I know I have this otUdpReceive(instance, onMessageReceived, &socket); wrong but I can't figure out the documentation to fix it. This line is supposed to set up an asychronous function that calls onMessageReceived when a message is received.
Here is more code context (it is in initThreadDevice)
if (otUdpBind(instance, &socket, &bindAddr, OT_NETIF_THREAD) == OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("UDP socket bound to port.");

        // Set the UDP receive callback
        otUdpReceive(instance, onMessageReceived, &socket); // Register the callback
    } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to bind UDP socket.");
    }
}

Here is the complete code.
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <openthread/thread.h>
#include <openthread/udp.h>
#include <openthread/message.h>
#include <openthread/dataset.h>
#include <openthread/instance.h>
#include <openthread/tasklet.h>

#define THREAD_CHANNEL 15

otInstance *instance;
otUdpSocket socket;

// Callback function to handle received messages
void onMessageReceived(void *aContext, otMessage *aMessage, const otMessageInfo *aMessageInfo) {

    // Retrieve the Mesh-Local EID
    const otIp6Address *meshLocalEid = otThreadGetMeshLocalEid(instance);
    if (meshLocalEid == NULL) {
        Serial.println("Failed to retrieve Mesh-Local EID.");
        return;
    }

    // Compare the Mesh-Local EID with the source address of the incoming message
    if (otIp6IsAddressEqual(meshLocalEid, &aMessageInfo->mPeerAddr)) {
        Serial.println("Ignoring message from self.");
        return;  // Ignore the message if it's from this device
    }

    char messageBuffer[128];
    int maxLength = sizeof(messageBuffer) - 1;  // Set maximum message length (128 - 1 for null termination)
    
    // Read the incoming message, but clip it if it's too long
    int length = otMessageRead(aMessage, otMessageGetOffset(aMessage), messageBuffer, maxLength);
    
    // Ensure the message is null-terminated
    if (length > 0) {
        messageBuffer[length] = '\0';  // Add null termination at the end of the message
    } else {
        return;  // If no valid length, just return
    }

    // Print the received message
    Serial.print("Received message: ");
    Serial.println(messageBuffer);
}

// Try to join an existing Thread network
bool joinExistingNetwork(otOperationalDataset &dataset) {
    if (dataset.mComponents.mIsActiveTimestampPresent) {
        if (otDatasetSetActive(instance, &dataset) == OT_ERROR_NONE) {
            Serial.println("Joined existing Thread network.");
            return true;
        } else {
            Serial.println("Failed to join the network.");
        }
    } else {
        Serial.println("No active Thread network found.");
    }

    return false;
}

// Form a new Thread network
bool formNewThreadNetwork(otOperationalDataset &dataset) {
    Serial.println("Forming a new Thread network...");

    memset(&dataset, 0, sizeof(dataset));  // Clear the dataset

    // Set the network parameters (example values, you can adjust them)
    dataset.mActiveTimestamp.mSeconds = 1;  // Set timestamp in seconds
    dataset.mActiveTimestamp.mTicks = 0;    // Set ticks (usually 0)
    dataset.mActiveTimestamp.mAuthoritative = true;  // Mark as authoritative
    dataset.mComponents.mIsActiveTimestampPresent = true;
    dataset.mComponents.mIsActiveTimestampPresent = true;
    
    dataset.mChannel = THREAD_CHANNEL;  // Set the desired channel
    dataset.mComponents.mIsChannelPresent = true;

    dataset.mPanId = 0x1234;  // Set a random PAN ID
    dataset.mComponents.mIsPanIdPresent = true;

    const char* networkName = "MyThreadNetwork";
    strcpy(dataset.mNetworkName.m8, networkName);  // Set the network name
    dataset.mComponents.mIsNetworkNamePresent = true;

    // Apply the new dataset to form the network
    if (otDatasetSetActive(instance, &dataset) == OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("New Thread network formed.");
        return true;
    } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to form the new Thread network.");
    }

    return false;
}

// Initialize Thread device and set up UDP communication
void initThreadDevice() {
    Serial.println("Initializing Thread...");

    Serial.println("Detecting there are any existing networks...");
    otOperationalDataset dataset;

    if (otDatasetGetActive(instance, &dataset) == OT_ERROR_NONE) {
      Serial.println("Active Thread network found. Attempting to join...");
      if (!joinExistingNetwork(dataset)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to join the existing network. Exiting prematurely from initThreadDevice.");
        return;
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("No active Thread network found. Attempting to create a new network...");
      if (!formNewThreadNetwork(dataset)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to create a new network. Exiting prematurely from initThreadDevice.");
        return;
      }
    }

    // Try to start the Thread protocol
    if (otThreadSetEnabled(instance, true) == OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("Thread network enabled.");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to start Thread network.");
        return;
    }

    // Set up UDP socket and bind it to a port
    otSockAddr bindAddr;
    memset(&bindAddr, 0, sizeof(bindAddr));
    bindAddr.mPort = 12345;  // Example port number

if (otUdpBind(instance, &socket, &bindAddr, OT_NETIF_THREAD) == OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("UDP socket bound to port.");

        // Set the UDP receive callback
        otUdpReceive(instance, onMessageReceived, &socket); // Register the callback
    } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to bind UDP socket.");
    }
}

void broadcastMessage(const char *message) {
    delay(random(100, 500));
    otMessageInfo messageInfo;
    memset(&messageInfo, 0, sizeof(messageInfo));  // Clear the messageInfo structure

    // Set the destination to the IPv6 link-local multicast address ff02::1 (all nodes)
    if (otIp6AddressFromString("ff02::1", &messageInfo.mPeerAddr) != OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("Invalid multicast address.");
        return;
    }
    messageInfo.mPeerPort = 12345;  // Specify the port to send the message

    // Create a new UDP message
    otMessage *udpMessage = otUdpNewMessage(instance, NULL);
    if (udpMessage == NULL) {
        Serial.println("Failed to create new UDP message.");
        return;
    }

    // Append the message to the UDP message buffer
    if (otMessageAppend(udpMessage, message, strlen(message)) != OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("Failed to append message content.");
        otMessageFree(udpMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Send the message via UDP to the multicast address
    otUdpSend(instance, &socket, udpMessage, &messageInfo);

    Serial.println("Broadcast message sent.");
    otMessageFree(udpMessage);
}

void sendMessageToLeader(const char *message) {
    delay(random(100, 500));
    otMessageInfo messageInfo;
    memset(&messageInfo, 0, sizeof(messageInfo));  // Clear the messageInfo structure

    // Get the leader's RLOC (Routing Locator)
    otIp6Address leaderAddress;
    if (otThreadGetLeaderRloc(instance, &leaderAddress) != OT_ERROR_NONE) {
        Serial.println("Failed to get leader address.");
        return;
    }

    // Set the destination to the leader's address
    messageInfo.mPeerAddr = leaderAddress;
    messageInfo.mPeerPort = 12345;  // Specify the port to send the message

    // Create a new UDP message
    otMessage *udpMessage = otUdpNewMessage(instance, NULL);
    if (udpMessage == NULL) {
        Serial.println("Failed to create new UDP message.");
        return;
    }

    // Append the message to the UDP message buffer
if (otMessageAppend(udpMessage, message, strlen(message)) != OT_ERROR_NONE) {
    Serial.println("Failed to append message content.");
    otMessageFree(udpMessage);
    return;
}
    // Send the message via UDP to the leader's address
    otUdpSend(instance, &socket, udpMessage, &messageInfo);

    Serial.println("Message sent to the network leader.");
    otMessageFree(udpMessage);
}

bool isLeader() {
    otDeviceRole role = otThreadGetDeviceRole(instance);  // Get the current role of the device

    if (role == OT_DEVICE_ROLE_LEADER) {
      return true;
    } 

    return false;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Starting ESP32-C6 Thread communication...");

    // Initialize the OpenThread instance
    instance = otInstanceInitSingle();

    // Initialize Thread device (attempt to join or form a network)
    initThreadDevice();
}

void loop() {
    // Send test messages periodically (for leader or node)
    if (isLeader()) {
        broadcastMessage("Hello from the leader.");
    } else {
        sendMessageToLeader("Hello from a node.");
    }

    // Delay between message exchanges
    delay(5000);

    // OpenThread processes should be called periodically
    otTaskletsProcess(instance);
}


You have only one specific question : Why do I get this compilation error. Reduce your question's code to the point where with a few lines you can get the the compiler the same error, then show that here. Also list the type of the compiler and its version. The compiler error means you're not using standard C++ somewhere.

If I've found the correct documentation, otUdpReceive is defined as typedef void(*otUdpReceive) (void *aContext, otMessage *aMessage, const otMessageInfo *aMessageInfo). You can't call a typedef.

David, if the purpose of otUdpReceive(instance, onMessageReceived, &socket); is to register a callback, then ask yourself, "to what?" and also "where is the callback going?".
